# Browser appears to be adding attributes to HTML code

Tags: html, image, browser

This is the HTML that appears in several different browsers.

```
<img title="Home" class="homeicon" draggable="false" alt="Home" src="/img/template/home-icon.png" border="0">
```

This is the code in the actual HTML file.

```
   <img title="Home" class="homeicon" alt="Home" src="/img/template/home-icon.png">
```

I am assuming that the browser is adding additional presentational attributes.
I have tried to use

```
-webkit-appearance:none; and -moz-appearance:none;
```

with the same results.

Can someone point me in the right direction to track down where the code is coming from and how to remove it?

It is important to remove these attributes to make the site more ADA compliant.

Comment: I've never heard of a browser doing this on its own, are you sure there isn't a server-side filter or Javascript plugin running?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: If the raw HTML coming from the server says one thing and inspecting the page after it's loaded says a different thing, then some bit of JavaScript is to blame. (The browser absolutely will not add those attributes on its own, but some bit of script might.) If what's in your HTML file differs from what a raw HTTP request returns, then it's something on the server that's at fault.

Comment: I guess it could be possible that something is coming from my content management system, but when I look at the html code in the browser it shows correctly while when I inspect just that element the additional presentation items are there. That is why I was thinking browser

Comment: OK, thanks to all of you. We finally tracked down a .js file that was adding the extra code.